# Increasing numbers in string based on leading word

Tags: java, python, parsing

I have large text files and they each contain strings of words and numbers. 
I need to increase those numbers by a fixed value and write them right back to where they were before within that string.

The value that I want to add depends on the word that came before the number, and every number that has none of these keywords must **not** be increased.

My approach would be to split at space characters, check for the words and handle the digit after, whenever I find the keyword. However, this leaves me with the requirement of having space characters between word and number and that is not ensured.

Furthermore, when reassembling the string from the split array, this might break the layout from before.

An example could be 
"Mark is quite large, 189cm, and was born in the year 1978. However, he has only 1 question concerning parsing, that he really can't get his head around."

After large, the height should be increased by 5 and after year, the number subtracted by 19. The number 1 should stay untouched, as only is not a keyword.

I can work with both, java or python, as these are the languages I know.

Comment: That is both broad and asks for opinion answers and external libraries so it is really off topic here.

Comment: I removed my search for libraries. Please let me know how to make my question less broad. Edit: I added an example to make it clearer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i got something:

```
public class Start {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Test String
        String s = "not4inc6desc3inc14";

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(s);

        //keep track where new word begins
        int newWord = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++){

            //chekc if the new Character is a number
            if(checkNumber(sb.substring(i, i+1))){

                //if the old word ends with "inc"
                //maybe try out .contains()
                if(sb.substring(newWord, i).endsWith("inc")){
                    //replace number
                    StringBuffer temp = new StringBuffer();
                    int j  = 0;

                    //get full number
                    for(j = i; j < sb.length() && checkNumber(sb.substring(j, j+1)); j++){
                        temp.append(sb.substring(j, j+1));
                    }

                    //modify number
                    int number = Integer.parseInt(temp.toString()) + 1;

                    //replace number
                    sb.replace(i, i + temp.length(), Integer.toString(number));

                    //number no longer needs to be checked for being a word
                    i=j;
                }
            }
        }

        //print test String
        System.out.println(sb.toString());

    }

    // Check if String is numeric
    private static boolean checkNumber(String s){
        try{
            Integer.parseInt(s);
        }catch(NumberFormatException e ){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I'm sorry it's a bit hard to understand... feel free to ask...

Comment: This seems like an appropriate approach. I will add my handling of different keywords, but your snippet helps me a lot with it. Thanks!